# How to reverse direction of motor without using IC driver module?

Tags: arduino

Please help me here. I am quite on leash with an arduino project and the IC module, which I ordered from Amazon is not working and I have to present it tomorrow. If you have any idea how to reverse direction of a motor without using an IC driver module, please help me.

Comment: think how you could use 4 relays to change the polarity of the motor. then figure out how to replace the relays with a non-mover, like a logic-level mosfet.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what type of motor or how you want it to run or any of the type of details that would be needed to really answer your question.  But I'm guessing that you have a brushed DC motor and are wanting to be able to run it both directions.  That can be done without the IC using 4 transistors and a few other parts.  Google "H-Bridge Circuit" for more information.  I'm guessing that the motor driver module which you ordered has an IC on it that serves as an H-bridge.

If you want a better answer than that, you'll have to add some details to your question.